# Xcode error? Use of undeclared identifier

Tags: xcode, build, xcode5

I am trying to build a project, yet it keeps saying that it has use of undeclared identifier 'QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND' ... This phrase is keeping me from building

```
spatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
```

Comment: Ok, so i have that problem fixed, i just need help on this one.

Comment: dyldaii = (dyld_all_image_infos *) readMem;  THIS Phrase says its an expected expression Please Help!!

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post a new question.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help